# Как передать в lambda-функцию текущее значение переменной?

Tags: python, lambda

Писал простенький калькулятор в tkinter. Некоторые кнопки инициализировал в цикле:

```
for i in range(10):
   button = Button(command=lambda: some_function(i), ...)
```

Проблема в том, что лямбда функции запоминают не текущее значение переменной, а ее *адрес*. То есть, после окончания цикла я получу десять кнопок, вызывающих одну и ту же функцию с одним и тем же аргументом (`some_function(9)`). Как можно обойти эту особенность, передав *значения* переменной `i` (чтобы кнопки вызывали функции: `some_function(1)`, `some_function(2)` и т. д.) ?

Вот, как это выглядит сейчас:

```
from tkinter import *

def enter_digit(number):
    print(number)

root = Tk()

for i in range(9):
    button_column, button_row = i % 3, i // 3
    button = Button(root, text=str(i+1), command=lambda: enter_digit(i + 1))
    button.grid(column=button_column, row=button_row)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это обычное поведение замыканий в питон. Так как все лямбды создаются в одной и то й же области видимости, то они все указывают на одну и ту же переменную (счетчик цикла `i` в данном случае).

Обойти можно несколькими способами. Первый - это создавать лямбду в фукнции:

```
def createCommand(i):
  return lambda: some_function(i)

...
for i in range(10):
   button = Button(commnand=createCommand(i), ...)
```

Второй, более элегантный как по мне, вариант, это создать параметр со значением по-умолчанию:

```
for i in range(10):
   button = Button(command=lambda i=i: some_function(i), ...)
```

Тут используется тот факт, что значение по умолчанию вычисляется в момент определения функции или лябмды.

Comment: Второй вариант действительно очень красив, моё почтение

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *

def enter_digit(number, buf=0):                              # buf ??? 
    print(number)

root = Tk()

for i in range(9):
    button_column, button_row = i % 3, i // 3
#                                                       vvvvv              v    
    button = Button(root, text=str(i+1), command=lambda i=i+1: enter_digit(i))
    button.grid(column=button_column, row=button_row)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать отдельную функцию, которая будет возвращать нужную вам лямбда-функцию. То, как это работает у вас:

```
>>> l = []
>>> for i in range(10):
...   l += [lambda: str(i)]
...
>>> l[0]()
'9'
>>> l[5]()
'9'
>>> l[9]()
'9'
```

Как это можно решить:

```
>>> def wrap(function, *args):
...     return lambda: function(*args)
...
>>> l = []
>>> for i in range(10):
...   l += [wrap(str, i)]
...
>>> l[0]()
'0'
>>> l[5]()
'5'
>>> l[9]()
'9'
```