# Как оформить передачу функций, нескольких создаваемых кнопок (число неизвестно) не через список и анонимные функции

Tags: python, pyqt6

Пытаюсь запихнуть все кнопки в словарь, так как не вижу другого варианта назначать разные команды этим кнопкам. При привязке через анонимную функцию, у всех кнопок сохраняется последняя команда, которая была объявлена через one

````
    def set_(self, whatset):
        global buttons
        self.textEdit.setText(self.notes_[whatset])
        self.current = whatset
    def reload_(self): # Перезагрузка области просмотра заметок
        global buttons, spliter
        file = open("Some.txt", "r")
        arg = file.read().split("///")[1]
        notes = os.listdir("/".join(__file__.split("\\")[:-1])+"/resourses")
        self.notes_ = {} #Словарь расшифрованных заметок, ключи - названия заметок
        for name in notes:
            file1 = open("/".join(__file__.split("\\")[:-1])+"/resourses/"+name, 'r')
            textIn = sm.decrypt(file1.read(), arg)
            file1.close()
            name = sm.decrypt(name, arg)
            self.notes_[name] = textIn
        print(self.notes_)
        for one in self.notes_: # Изменение размера кнопок в зависимости от объёма содержимого 
            buttons[one] = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            if len(one)> 25:
                buttons[one].setText(spliter(20, one))
            else:
                buttons[one].setText(one)
                buttons[one].clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_(one))
                buttons[one].setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border: 2 solid rgb(20, 23, 48);\n"
"height: 51;"
"border-radius: 20;}"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"background-color: white;\n"
"color: rgb(20, 23, 48);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"color: green;\n"
"border: 2 solid white;\n"
"border-radius: 20;}")
            # Шрифт кнопок
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI")
            font.setPointSize(14)
            font.setBold(False)
            font.setWeight(50)
            buttons[one].setFont(font)
            self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(buttons[one])
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.textEdit.setText("")```
````

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1237170/218971

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: вы можете попробовать заменить строку `buttons[one].clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_(one))` на строку `buttons[one].clicked.connect(lambda ch, one=one: self.set_(one))`. но мне почему-то кажется, что у вас будут проблемы в дальнейшем.

Comment: @S.Nick не знаю как, но ваш способ действительно сработал. Огромное вам спасибо, но почему в дальнейшем у меня могут быть проблемы? Вы имеете ввиду именно эту строку, или моё написание кода в целом?

Comment: anonymus, пожалуйста. Если вы хотите получать быстрые и правильные ответы - всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример. Глобальные переменные - это зло. Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.